# Share an instance of NSURLCache between an app and extension in a Swift framework

Tags: swift, nsurlcache

I want to share an instance of `NSURLCache` between my app and an extension so tried instantiating it from a Swift framework.

Is there any way to spawn the URL cache on a shared (container) disk space?